# C# : decode cookies

Tags: c#, cookies, decode

i got problem with libraries , now i write a program to read cookies and some cookies are being encoded so i need to decode them and i know that i must use the library System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode to decode the cookies but whenever i type Using System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode i get no library it just stop at Using System.Web; nothing more no subs of Web . i am using .net frame2 and i tried that on .net framework 4 and didn`t work . i dont use ASP i use a console application . and thanks a lot in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Add the namespace to your project references.

Right click on references -> add reference -> .NET -> Select `System.Web` -> click add

Comment: Which framework version are you targetting? Client Profile does not have that namespace afaik.

Comment: Do you only not get intellisense for that library? Try compiling code accessing that namespace. If you cannot compile i would assume that something is wrong with your .NET install. A repair of your Visual Studio installation might help in this case.

Comment: i found  HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode instead , but cant use it